# 3 men, 3 women and 4 children are to be seated at a round table. In how many ways can a particular women be seated between a man and a child?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> 3 men, 3 women and 4 children are to be seated at a round table. In how many ways can a particular women be seated between a man and a child?

Answer is $120960$.

My attempt: I pair each man with a child. So I have 3 pairs. It is a round table, so there are $(4-1)!×2^3$ to arrange the 3 pairs and a child. But I do not know how to slot in one of the women so that the condition is satisfied.

Comment: May I post the correct calculation?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel: Sure, go ahead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct calculation is

- 3 ways to select the man, and 4 ways to select the child, sitting next to the indicated woman
- 2 ways to arrange those two neighbours around the woman
- $7!$ ways to arrange the rest of the guests

leading to a total of 120960 ways as given.